# Non-negative martingale $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. prove that $P[X^* \geq x | \mathcal{F}_0]= 1 \wedge X_0 / x$

Tags: probability, martingales, stopping-times

I need to prove the following statement.

Let $X$ be a non negative martingale such that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ a.s. when $n\rightarrow \infty$. Define $X^*=supX_n$. Prove that for all $x>0$

$$P[X^*  \geq x | \mathcal{F}_0]= 1 \wedge X_0 / x$$

I think I've got the easy case

- if  $x\leq X_0$

Then necessarily $x\leq X^*$ for the sup property. Then it follows that for $1\leq X_0 /x$ we have that $P[X^*  \geq x | \mathcal{F}_0]= 1$. But I can't figure out the other case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{t \geq 0} M_t \geq x \mid \mathcal{F}_0) = 1 \wedge \frac{M_0}{x}$ for a martingale $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239524/prove-mathbbp-sup-t-geq-0-m-t-x-mid-mathcalf-0-1-wedge-fracm)

Comment: or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238896/supremal-distribution-of-positive-continuous-martingale-which-converges-to-zero?rq=1

Comment: This is great thank you!